# Transfer a 3d image with a certain color map to 2d image with certain int values

Tags: python, numpy

For [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPUoO.png) 3d image, it have 6 classes, which are:

```
Impervious surfaces (RGB: 255, 255, 255)
Building (RGB: 0, 0, 255)
Low vegetation (RGB: 0, 255, 255)
Tree (RGB: 0, 255, 0)
Car (RGB: 255, 255, 0)
Clutter/background (RGB: 255, 0, 0)
```

I would like to transfer this image to a 2d image, where

```
Impervious surfaces --> 0
Building --> 1
Low vegetation --> 2
Tree --> 3
Car --> 4
Clutter/background --> 5
```

I could only figure out to use for loop as:

```
im = imageio.imread('kPUoO.png')
w,h = im.shape[:2]
im_ = np.zeros((w,h), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(w):
    for j in range(h):
        if list(im[i,j]) == [0,0,255]:
            im_[i,j] = 1
        if list(im[i,j]) == [0,255,255]:
            im_[i,j] = 2
        if list(im[i,j]) == [0,255,0]:
            im_[i,j] = 3
        if list(im[i,j]) == [255,255,0]:
            im_[i,j] = 4
        if list(im[i,j]) == [255,0,0]:
            im_[i,j] = 5
```

I am wondering is there any simpler way to this work. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your data was *originally* just six classes, but now it has more.  For example, `im[0, 0]` is `[ 14, 255, 237]`.  There are over 4000 different colors in that image.  The image is stored in the [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) format, which is a [lossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format.  If you originally had just the six colors mentioned in the question, and you want to preserve those values exactly in the image file, use a lossless format such as [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

Comment: Okay, I see it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to think about the more general problem, where you could have any value from 0 to 255 present in each band, or even more than 3 bands...

We can encode the positions of 0's and 255's by applying a different bit shift to each column (0 to 3 bits for zeros in columns 0, 1, and/or 2, and 4 to 6 bits for 255's in columns 0, 1 and/or 2):

```
a = (im == 0) << numpy.array([0,1,2], numpy.uint8)
a += (im == 255) << numpy.array([3,4,5], numpy.uint8)
```

The sum along the last axis then uniquely encodes the classes. The division by 7 is not necessary, it just gives simpler class labels.

```
numpy.add.reduce(a, -1) // 7
```

From there it is a standard 1:1 map to re-label the classes. I think for larger images, or large numbers of images, this approach may be faster.

To see how this works:

```
0,0,0 = 1<<0 + 1<<1 + 1<<2 + 0<<3 + 0<<4 + 0<<5 = 7, /7 = 1
0,0,255 = 1<<0 + 1<<1 + 0<<2 + 0<<3 + 0<<4 + 1<<5 = 35, /7 = 5
0,255,255 = 1<<0 + 0<<1 + 0<<2 + 0<<3 + 1<<4 + 1<<5 = 49, /7 = 7
255,255,255 = 0<<0 + 0<<1 + 0<<2 + 1<<3 + 1<<4 + 1<<5 = 56, /7 = 8
etc...
```

An equivalent formulation is:

```
a = (im == 0) * numpy.array([1,2,4], numpy.uint8)
a += (im == 255) * numpy.array([8,16,32], numpy.uint8)
numpy.add.reduce(a, -1) //7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
im = imageio.imread('kPUoO.png')
w,h = im.shape[:2]
im_ = np.zeros((w,h), dtype=np.uint8)
pos1 = np.where((im[:,:,0]==0) & (im[:,:,1]==0) & (im[:,:,2]==255))
pos2 = np.where((im[:,:,0]==0) & (im[:,:,1]==255) & (im[:,:,2]==255))
pos3 = np.where((im[:,:,0]==0) & (im[:,:,1]==255) & (im[:,:,2]==0))
pos4 = np.where((im[:,:,0]==255) & (im[:,:,1]==255) & (im[:,:,2]==0))
pos5 = np.where((im[:,:,0]==255) & (im[:,:,1]==0) & (im[:,:,2]==0))
im_[pos1] = 1
im_[pos2] = 2
im_[pos3] = 3
im_[pos4] = 4
im_[pos5] = 5
```